# How to inspect db in django2.1 with postgresql?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, inspectdb

hi when i run `python3 manage.py inspectdb`
it will return following error
`# The error was: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'`

same `python3 manage.py inspectdb` working on sqlite when i use postgresql it will return error

`# Unable to inspect table 'zip_code`
`# The error was: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'`

Comment: i am using Django==2.1 and psycopg2==2.8.3

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include that detail, not a comment, and also include the tracebacks

Comment: How did you install Django and psycopg2? Did you use a virtual environment? Did you use Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Can you run `python3 manage.py dbshell`, that should put you into the postgres cli (psql), and from there try `\d zip_code`. This should show the schema of the table that is giving a problem.

Comment: **Chris** i am using python3.6 and iam not using virtula environment